# How can I do an irregular exagon using css?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I wanna do this shape using css

[image]

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
  
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Be careful though. A regular hexagon with equal side lenghts and the width `w` (as diagonal)  has the height `sqrt(3)/2*w` In this example, the height should be defined as `86.6px`.